# Android button dynamically placed on button

Tags: android, layout, button, gravity

I wanted to know if there is a way to place a button on the bottom of the screen, no matter what size screen the device has. I basically want the button to have a gravity="bottom", not just its text. I have been trying to do this, and I cannot find a way to do it. any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post the XML you are currently using? It's hard to debug layouts without knowing what kind of layout it is in (such as `LinearLayout`, 'RelativeLayout`, etc), and what other views are in the same layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I created a child LinearLayout only for  and I put

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

in the child and it worked :-)

Answer (score 1):

What layout is the button in?  Using a relative layout, you can set the button to [align_parent_bottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM).

Answer (score 1):

use a `RelativeLayout` with `layout_height="fill_parent"` then set the button's `layout_alignParentBottom` value to `true` in the XML file

Answer (score 0):

Try using android:layout_gravity="bottom" on the Button :)

Comment: I've tried it, it doesn't work :-( it stays right where it is lol I have: <Button 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="80px"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"

Comment: (Assuming you're using a LinearLayout) And that's the fun of LinearLayout :) Maybe try using RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout?